# Django ignoring environment variables when run via uWSGI

Tags: django, uwsgi

I have a django website, that uses an environment variable, `DJANGO_MODE` to decide which settings to use - development or staging. The environment variable is in the `bashrc` and when running the app using the development server, everything works fine.

But when I run the app using `uWSGI`, it doesn't seem to notice the environment variable and uses the default(development) settings instead of production.

I run `uWSGI` in Emperor mode, and other than the environment variable ignoring, everything seems to be running fine. And yes, the user running `uWSGI` is the same for which the `bashrc` has `DJANGO_MODE` set.

The command used to run `uWSGI` is -

```
exec  uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid web_user --gid --web_user
```

And the `ini` file for the vassal -

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 2
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
wsgi-file = /home/web_user/web/project_dir/project/wsgi.py
chdir = /home/web_user/web/project_dir
virtualenv = /home/web_user/.virtualenvs/production_env
logger = syslog
chmod-socket = 777
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It cannot work as bash config files are read by the bash. You have to set var in the emperor or in the vassal (the second one is a better approach). Just add

```
env=DJANGO_MODE=foobar
```

to your config (do not use whitespace).

Comment: add some print to check if DJANGO_MODE is available in os.environ, maybe you have some other kind of problem. Take in account DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set at the very beginning so the check has to happen in wsgi.py

Comment: Doh! I had the env set with spaces in it - `env = DJANGO_MODE = mode`, which was causing problems.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, I don't want to put env vars into uWSGI config, since `manage.py` also needs them.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670960/