# How to avoid putting environment variables into multiple places with Django, nginx and uWSGI?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to configure nginx+uWSGI to serve my Django application.

When I put environment variables into `myapp_uwsgi.ini`:

```bash
uid = username
gid = username
env = DJANGO_SITE_KEY="..."
```

it works as expected.

However, my app has some [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) which should also have access to the environment variables I have defined.

If I put the environment variables to `/home/username/.bashrc`:

```bash
export DJANGO_SITE_KEY="..."
```

uWSGI does not load them.

I have tried to put the environment variables into a separate file:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
export DJANGO_SITE_KEY="..."
```

and then call it from both `.bashrc`:

```bash
. /home/username/environment
```

and `myapp_uwsgi.ini`:

```bash
exec-pre-app = . /home/username/environment
```

In uWSGI logs I see this line:

```bash
running ". /home/username/environment" (pre app)...
```

But my Django app is unable to access the environment variables with `os.environ`.

I have also tried putting the `export` commands to the `preactivate` hook of virtualenvwrapper and use the `virtualenv =` setting of uWSGI, but it does not work too (I assume the hooks are only executed when using virtualenvwrapper commands like `workon`.

Answer (score 29):

Here is [the answer](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/629#issuecomment-43303330) from uWSGI developers:

> just place each of them (one per line) in a text file in the form
>
> VAR=VALUE
>
> then in uWSGI config
>
> ```
> [uwsgi]
> for-readline = yourfile
>   env = %(_)
> endfor =
> ```

This also works with yml config files:

```
  for-readline: filename
    env: %(_)
  endfor:
```

Comment: And what about for management commands - parsing the text file with bash?

Comment: Do you mean parsing `myapp_uwsgi.ini`? I don't think it is a right approach. Changing the web server would break the things.

Comment: Nah, is the parsing of the txt file is the right approach.
I went with you approach and I'm parsing the txt file with env variables in the activate script of the venv.

Comment: Note that the values **should not be quoted**, since [uWSGI doesn't drop quotes](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1089) when parsing the file. If you do quote them, you have to strip quotes from all values when using them in your application.

Comment: What about `export` keyword with this approach? Exporting environment variables is useful if you use any tools which need to know location of specific directories and files.

Comment: you can `export` them yourself later, if needed:
`source filename; export VAR=$VAR`

Comment: To export all variables in the env file: `set -a; source filename; set +a`

Answer (score 2):

I use [django-dotenv](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv). Put your env vars in a file like .env inside your project, and then load it in manage.py and wsgi.py. No other config required. uwsgi and manage.py commands will work as expected, and all your env vars are stored in just one file.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using configuration management systems such as [Salt](http://www.saltstack.com/) or [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/).

With them one can create Jinja templates for both uWSGI and Django with {{ variables }} defined in one place.