# How do I pass env variables to uwsgi?

Tags: python, uwsgi, wsgi

I have a WSGI handler configured under Apache and I'm defining some environmental variables in the Apache virtual host configuration.

```
SetEnv APP_CONFIG "/var/lib/myapp/app.config"
SetEnv LOG_CONFIG "/var/lib/myapp/app.logging.yml"
```

To test the handler in development without having to install and configure Apache I'm using `uWSGI` with the `--http` option.

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --ini uwsgi.ini --wsgi-file wsgi.py
```

wsgi.py

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    config_file_path = environ['APP_CONFIG']
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return ["Hello World"]
```

Using the uWSGI http server how can I pass these variables to my application as part of the `environ` argument?

I have tried setting environmental variables in the uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
env = APP_CONFIG="/var/lib/myapp/app.config"
```

but I get:

```
File "wsgi.py", line 5, in application
config_file_path = environ['APP_CONFIG']
KeyError: 'APP_CONFIG'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
[uwsgi]
env             = RAY_REDIS_PASS=ray_pass
env             = RAY_REDIS_PORT=6380
strict          = true
chdir           = /Users/judas/projects/myapp
master-fifo     = /tmp/myapp_fifo0
master-fifo     = /tmp/myapp_fifo1
module          = myapp.wsgi:application
master          = true
vacuum          = true
need-app        = true
processes       = 4
die-on-term     = true
procname-prefix = myapp
harakiri        = 30
socket          = /tmp/myapp_uwsgi.sock
lazy-apps       = true
logger          = file:logfile=/tmp/apps.log,maxsize=2000000000
import          = postfork
```

Comment: broken link, and not at wayback machine. do you have another that works? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18490958/3383797 **do not use whitespaces**:

```
[uwsgi]
env=MY_VAR_NAME=foobar
```

Comment: This is quite odd since INI files' key values don't normally require spaces. Does this mean only using the `env` option requires omitting white space?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to specify you .ini file

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --http = :9090 --wsgi-file wsgi.py
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing that and I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Phill Sorry my bad. Can you post your entire WSGI.py file.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered how to do this using `addvar` in the `wsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
route-run = addvar:APP_CONFIG="/var/lib/myapp/app.config"
```